# Textures rotated 90 degrees when importing a .glb file

Tags: 3d, blender, godot

I have a simple box, textured with bricks, in Blender:

[image]

I export this scene as glTF 2.0 and import into Godot. Here's the result:

[image: 1]

As you can see, the bricks are rotated 90 degrees for some reason. Why, and how can I make it right?

Comment: Are you, perhaps, rotating the texture in the material?

Comment: What does that mean? How to rotate the texture in the material?

Comment: Godot - and other engines - will not import everything you can do with Blender materials. You could flip the x and y coordinates or rotate the texture in Blender visual shader language. Don't expect me to explain how to do it on Blender, that is not my expertise. *In fact, there is [a stack exchange site for that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).* What I can tell you is that only the most basic Blender materials translate to Godot without issues, I know this from experience working on Godot with models from a colleague who works on Blender.

Comment: Thank you for that link, I'll ask there.